# Что такое Контекстный поиск (contextualized lookup) в Ioc (Inversion of Control)?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control

Смотрим, например тут [Википедия. Инверсия управления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) 
Способы реализации Инверсия управления (IoC):
1)Шаблон «Фабрика» (англ. Factory pattern)
2)Локатор служб
3)Внедрение зависимости (англ. Dependency injection)
____3.1 Через конструктор (англ. Constructor injection)
____3.2 Через метод класса (англ. Setter injection)
____3.3 Через интерфейс внедрения (англ. Interface injection)
**4)Контекстный поиск (англ. contextualized lookup)**

Что это за загадочный зверь такой <4)Контекстный поиск (англ. contextualized lookup)>???
Не могу найти описание на него((
Помогите! Объясните или поделитесь ссылками.
Интересуют примеры на C#.
Спасибо!

Comment: Цитата из английской Вики: "Often the contextualized lookup will be accomplished using a service locator". / Судя по статье Фаулера, в которой неоднократно упоминается lookup, регистрация зависимостей может осуществляться разными способами, т. е. в зависимости от _контекста_. Не только прямо в коде, но и поиском в файле конфига и т. п.

Comment: [Contextual Object Lookup](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/contextual-object-lookup) - судя по этому, если имеется связь компонентов A - B - C, то не только ближние могут взаимодействовать между собой (A и B, B и C), но и непрямые соседи: A и C.